# DataBinding from Entity Framework to Listivew dataSource

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, listview

My entity is returning the following:

```
class StoreClass{

    public Entry GetStoreInfo(int id, UserInfo userInfo)
    {
       using (var context = new StoreEntities())
       {
          var query = from a in context.Store
            .Include("Ratings")
            .Include("Versions")
            .Include("Versions.Installers")
            .Include("Versions.Installers.Screenshots")
            .Include("Category")
            where a.ID == id && a.IsActive 
         select a;
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
             }
    }
    }
```

I am trying to bind the data data returned form the above function to the listview.

```
StoreClass objStore = new StoreClass ();
            Listview1.DataSource = objStore .GetStoreInfo(1,userInfo);
            LstAppletInfo.DataBind();
        }
```

But its throwing an error "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource."

Help me solve this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Entry> GetStoreInfo(int id, UserInfo userInfo) 
{ 
    ...
    return query; 
}
```